# How would I clip numbers in a list based on upper and lower limits?

Tags: python, list, clipping

Here are the instructions:

Write a function called clipnums with three parameters – a list of numbers, a upper limit number, and a lower limit number. The function should return a new list where numbers lower than lower limit are replaced by the lower limit number and numbers higher than the upper limit number are replaced by the upper limit number.

This is an intorductory course for Python so I'm just learning and am working with the basics. :)

Below is my code

```
def clipnums(nums, u_limit, d_limit):
    newnums = []
    for i in nums:
        if i < d_limit:
            newnums.append(d_limit)
        elif i > u_limit:
            newnums.append(u_limit)
        else:
            newnums.append(i)
    return newnums
```

With the input

```
nums = [-1, 3, 0, 6, 8, 11, 20]
d_limit = 2
u_limit = 10
```

my code should return

```
[2, 3, 2, 6, 8, 10, 10]
```

However, it returns

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2]
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: You passed the arguments in the wrong order

Comment: Please update your question with the way that you actually call your function.

Comment: With the correct order, the function works fine: `clipnums(nums, u_limit, d_limit)` You might want to add a check that `u_limit >= d_limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution could be to just use min max. This makes it a bit easier.

```py
nums = [-1, 3, 0, 6, 8, 11, 20]
d_limit = 2
u_limit = 10

clipped_nums = [max(min(num, u_limit), d_limit) for num in nums]
```

To answer your question of why it doesn't work: didn't u just switch the `d_limit` and `u_limit` when calling your function?

```
>>> clipnums(nums, u_limit, d_limit)
[2, 3, 2, 6, 8, 10, 10]
>>> clipnums(nums, d_limit, u_limit)
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Switching the parameters resolved it. I figured it would be something simple-ish that would fix the error (I spent way too long fiddling with the code inside the function definition). My instructor gives specific parameters for testing and I had to match his function call with my function definition.